# If the option is selected, fills in the input

Tags: javascript, html

How, using only HTML and CSS, to make it so that when I select an option in `<select>`, my input is filled in?

Here is my code

```html
<select class="cod_art" name="cod_art" id="cod_art_01">
<option value="Default1">Default1</option>
<option value="Default2">Default2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="descrizione_01" name="descrizione" readonly>
```

So, if I select Default1 option, in input will fill a text, for example "example1". Just to make text in input different from the option value
How can I do it in JS?

Comment: Have you made any attempts yet?

Comment: @ChrisW. I tried using onchange and arrays but nothing works for me, I made research but appears only in Jquery, that I don't know

Comment: Where is the CSS? Did you mean "using only HTML and JavaScript"?

Comment: Where does it get the value `example1` from? How is it related to the options?

Comment: Why do both your options have the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("descrizione_01").value = document.getElementById("cod_art_01").options[0].dataset.text;
};

document.getElementById("cod_art_01").addEventListener("change", function(e){
    document.getElementById("descrizione_01").value = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].dataset.text;
});
```

```html
<select class="cod_art" name="cod_art" id="cod_art_01">
<option value="Default1" data-text="Example1">Default1</option>
<option value="Default2" data-text="Example2">Default2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="descrizione_01" name="descrizione" readonly>
```

Comment: Can I fill a text different from a value in option list? For example "Default1" - Example1?

Comment: @Walkie_UA Will the current edit work?

Comment: @Walkie_UA Just change the value of data-text to whatever you need it to be.

Comment: Thank you a lot, i didn't knew that i could do such a thing

Comment: @Walkie_UA No worries, I am happy to help out if I am able.